# Passing a string containing curly brackets to helm caused: Error: failed parsing --set data: key

Tags: bash, escaping, kubernetes-helm

`${CLIENT_ID}` and `${CLIENT_SECRET}` are both sourced from a yaml based properties file e.g

```
CLIENT_ID: 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
CLIENT_SECRET: '{aes}AM+JYP8t9ga1m6s111x1fjdfePL10v90RmbgWFdOjVdD/wlnszAbJad8aOI4qqMv6eSGaW2nfTF4PG2OYH+rx9K052TXNP6PGAAcRph9pl11'
```

using:

```
PROPERTIES_FILE="properties.yaml"
CLIENT_ID=$(yq r "${PROPERTIES_FILE}" CLIENT_ID)
CLIENT_SECRET=$(yq r "${PROPERTIES_FILE}" CLIENT_SECRET)
```

and then passed into my `helm` command for deploying my app:

```
echo ${CLIENT_ID}
# 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
echo ${CLIENT_SECRET}
# {aes}AM+JYP8t9ga1m6s111x1fjdfePL10v90RmbgWFdOjVdD/wlnszAbJad8aOI4qqMv6eSGaW2nfTF4PG2OYH+rx9K052TXNP6PGAAcRph9pl11

helm upgrade -i --debug  --namespace mynamespace release \
-f "charts/app/values.yaml" \
--set "app.configmap.dependancy.client_id=${CLIENT_ID}" \
--set "app.configmap.dependancy.client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}" \
"charts/app/"
```

`charts/app/values.yaml` contains:

```
app:
  ..
  configmap:
    dependancy:
      client_id: ""
      client_secret: ""
```

The problem is, I get this error when running the `helm` command:

```
Error: failed parsing --set-string data: key "AM+JYP8t9ga1m6s111x1fjdfePL10v90RmbgWFdOjVdD/wlnszAbJad8aOI4qqMv6eSGaW2nfTF4PG2OYH+rx9K052TXNP6PGAAcRph9pl11" has no value
No resources found.
```

Any idea why the prefixed `{aes}` is causing problems when passed into `helm` like this? The command works if I remove the `{aes}` prefix.

Comment: @alecxs this wraps the password with additional double quotes, which is not desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helm tries to make it possible to [pass some structured data in using `--set`](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set) and that's tripping you up here.  In particular,

> Lists can be expressed by enclosing values in `{` and `}`. For example, `--set name={a, b, c}` translates to [a list of `a`, `b`, and `c`].

So if you `--set 'key={aes}AM+JYP8...'`, the `{aes}` part looks like that list syntax but then there's things after it that Helm doesn't understand.

You can backslash-escape the curly braces, though that's a little tricky to do in shell syntax.  There's a `--set-string` option (documented in the [Helm 2 documentation](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set) but still present in Helm 3) that might be able to do this.  Possibly the most straightforward path, though, is to write out your own custom YAML values file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
PROPERTIES_FILE="properties.yaml"
CLIENT_ID=$(yq r "${PROPERTIES_FILE}" CLIENT_ID)
CLIENT_SECRET=$(yq r "${PROPERTIES_FILE}" CLIENT_SECRET)

cat >values.tmp.yaml <<EOF
app:
  configmap:
    dependancy:
      client_id: "${CLIENT_ID}"
      client_secret: "${CLIENT_SECRET}"
EOF

helm upgrade -i --debug --namespace mynamespace release \
  -f values.tmp.yaml charts/app
```

(You can have multiple `helm install -f` options if you need to.  The chart's `values.yaml` is read in automatically, and is overridden by command-line options.)

Comment: went with the option of `write out your own custom YAML values file`, thanks!